# Crystal reports formula error, remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create an if then formula to calculate various commissions depending on the sales totals achieved by the sales person.  Below is what I currently have. I get the error with the formula highlighted after the 501.

```
if Sum ({Employee_Sales_By_Rep.Grand_Total}, {Employee_Sales_By_Rep.Store_ID}) <500 then 
   sum ({Employee_Sales_By_Rep.Grand_Total}) * .10 
else 
   Sum ({Employee_Sales_By_Rep.Grand_Total}, {Employee_Sales_By_Rep.Store_ID}) > 501 then 
  sum ({Employee_Sales_By_Rep.Grand_Total}) * .20*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (Sum ({Employee_Sales_By_Rep.Grand_Total}, {Employee_Sales_By_Rep.Store_ID}) <500) then
sum ({Employee_Sales_By_Rep.Grand_Total}) * .10 else 
if (Sum ({Employee_Sales_By_Rep.Grand_Total}, {Employee_Sales_By_Rep.Store_ID}) > 501)
then sum ({Employee_Sales_By_Rep.Grand_Total}) * .20
```